# Submit form without using object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model

It's my first post on stackoverflow! I warn you, I just started learning Ruby on Rails.

Currently, I'm working on a music scanning project in rails. I'm trying to process al the music on the hard disk. To do that, the user can add a folder to scan when he is inside the config part of the app. So I store inside a YAML file all the config of my app.

I create a 'config' controller, that contains 2 view for the moment: "adddir" and "index".
The index view show all parameters, that have been gathered by loading the YAML config file (done by the controller 'config').

Next, I want to give the possibility to the user to add a new folder to scan. So I did a static route to the 'adddir' view:

routes.rb file:

```
match "/config/adddir" => "config#adddir"
```

Now, I want to create a form that get the path provided by the user, and add it to the YAML file.

So my question is: How to create a form that be able to use the method config#addfolder I created when the user click on submit button?

I hope this is enough clear.
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Its a very basic question. Just have a look at the screencast. Make a simple project first (with a model), then you will see the ABC of Rails.

http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts/rails3/

Basically:

You generate the controller like:

```
rails g controller config adddir
```

This setups the controller, the view and your route.

Then go into your view folder and look inside config. There is **adddir.html.erb**. This file you need to change in something like a form.

You can open your form:

```
http://localhost:3000/config/adddir
```

> rake routes

Will print you a list of available routes you can use (inside your form).

Now the magic is that Rails generate your a **config_adddir_path** (watch the **_path**). That you can use to hookup the form.

```
<%= form_tag(config_adddir_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Folder:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("index") %>
<% end %>
```

Inside your controller (def adddir):

You can access the parameters:

```
def adddir
  logger.debug params.inspect
end
```

Have a look here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: It is perfect! Thank you very much!
But I want to know... As I haven't any models, I can't check the information provided by the user? Or I can create a model that isn't linked to the database?

Moreover, I changed your 
    :method=>get

by :method=>adddir

Does it change anything?

Regards

Comment: Yes you can, the form fields are posted (despite model or not). In your action (adddir), you receive a hash: params. There you find the data of the formfields.